# Do Rokugan's Dragons have three or four toes?

Tags: lore, dragons, rokugan

I couldn't find it in what my collection gives me (or I am blind), but: is there a mention in the sources - or an official depiction - that details if Rokugani Dragons have three or four toes on their hands? I want to work out the description of a mural, but that detail eludes me, and the number has actual cultural significance, 4 being the typical civilian Chinese number, three the typical Japanese number

Or... might it be totally different and have five as depicted in some of the [TCG cards](http://www.playccg.com/catalog/l5r_singles-ivory_arc_singles-twenty_festivals/earth_dragon_experienced_2/114733) and reserved for the Chinese emperor traditionally?

To establish lore, let's assume the following hierarchy, top to bottom:

- *text* from Official RPG books for the Legends of the 5 Rings RPGs
- *text* from Oriental Adventures material *not* under the L5R rules but set in Rokugan
- *text* from Official Adventures not in the print products (aka an official campaign)
- Official L5R Novels *text* & CCG/LCG *fiction text*
- Official RPG *artwork*
- Official CCG/LCG *card text*
- Official CCG *artwork*

**Not** allowable as a source are *inofficial* texts and book covers from the novels. Fanzine contents is only permissible as supporting evidence.

Comment: So... just as a point of clarification, most of the official fiction is not in novel format.  https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/258529-fiction-library/ looks like it lists the stuff that's been published since Fantasy Flight took over, and https://kazenoshiro63445525.wordpress.com/ looks like it has the whole archive since forever.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Rokugan is a hodgepodge of japanese and chinese culture through a western lens. However, the number of toes on a dragon is culturally significant IRL: 5 toes is restricted for the Chinese Emperor, 4 is a Chinese "common" dragon, 3 is any dragon in Japan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It varies. My understanding from [this wiki entry](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Dragon#Appearances) is that dragons in L5R *choose* how they appear, so it's probably a matter of personal preference by the particular dragon.

**Four Toes**

[This Jade Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=4023)'s art depicts it as having four toes.
[This Air Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=174,#hashid=a485fa7b368a95c6c81ff79d4217f45e,#cardcount=2)'s art depicts it as having four toes. So does [this one](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=175,#hashid=a485fa7b368a95c6c81ff79d4217f45e,#cardcount=4) and [this one](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=12171,#hashid=a485fa7b368a95c6c81ff79d4217f45e,#cardcount=5).
[This Celestial Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=1252,#hashid=a485fa7b368a95c6c81ff79d4217f45e,#cardcount=14)'s art depicts it as having four toes.
[This Fire Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=12173)'s art depicts it as having four toes.

**Three Toes**

[This Black Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=10111,#hashid=a485fa7b368a95c6c81ff79d4217f45e,#cardcount=11)'s art depicts it as having three toes.
[This Earth Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=2258)'s art depicts it as having three toes. So does [this one](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=2260).
[This Fire Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=2562)'s art depicts it as having three toes.
[This Thunder Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=10067)'s art depicts it as having three toes.

**Others**

[This Earth Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=2259)'s art seems to depict it as having only *two* toes. Meanwhile, [this one](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=12172) gives it *five* toes.
[This Thunder Dragon](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=9175)'s card depicts it with five toes.
[This Fire Dragon card](https://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=2563)'s art seems to imply it doesn't even have *legs*.

Comment: interestingly, some of the cards do have a "thumb" claw, others do not.